# How to control a rc toy with Android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a rc drone. I want to create an Android app to control it but I do not know where to begin and how. I browsed the internet and found only one useful tutorial but it required use of Adruino and was through Bluetooth but I want to create my own Android app and not use Adruino or Raspberry Pi. Please help

Comment: Contact the manufacturers of your RC drone and ask them if they have an Android SDK to allow it to be controlled from some sort of Android app.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect via bluetooth (If you have no documentation of your RC drone it will be had to figure out the commands etc).

Maybe you can find a bluetooth sniffer program on the www to record what is going on when using the original hardware.

But I think its not worth the effort. To figure all this out will most likely take a lot of time and might not lead to success at all. So I recommend: next time by a drone where the communication protocol is documented or better a SDK is provided with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to figure out, if this drone uses Wifi or Bluetooth for control, or, some custom- build wireless device. If it use custom adapter, working on another frequency, you won't be able to do anything from software, only reverse- engineer control schematics.